# Python Session 10054 Connection Aborted Error

Tags: python, windows, session, web-scraping, python-requests

I wrote a web scraper using requests module. I open up a session and send subsequent requests using this session. It has 2 phases.

1) Scrape page by page and collect id's in an array.
2) Get details about each id in the array using requests to an ajax server on the same host.

The scraper works fine on my Linux machine. However when  I run the bot on Windows 10, phase 1 is completed just fine but after a couple of requests in phase 2 python throws this exception

File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 453, in send
    raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', error(10054, 'Varolan bir ba\xf0lant\xfd uzaktaki bir ana bilgisayar taraf\xfdndan zorla kapat\xfdld'))

What is different between two OS's which causes this? How can I overcome this problem?

Having modified my request code like below using retrying module had no positive effects. Now script doesn't throw exceptions but simply hangs doing nothing.

```
@retry(wait_exponential_multiplier=1000, wait_exponential_max=10000, stop_max_attempt_number=7)
def doReq(self, url):
    time.sleep(0.5)
    response = self.session.get(url, headers=self.headers)
    return response
```

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know why this problem occurs only in Windows. However, retrying decorator seems to have fixed the problem of socket error. The reason why the script hangs was due to the server not responding to a request. By default requests mode waits forever for a response. By adding a timeout value requests throws a timeout exception and retry decorator catches it and tries again. I know this is a work around rather than a solution but this is the best I've got right now.